# Inappropriate text to show user about a too-short question?

Tags: support, user-interface

See [How to show all function in a js file?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51686/105).

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

What caused this text to show?  Why would we tell a user who posed a **question** that we're looking for short **answers**?

Answer (score 1):

I've put up that notice.

This is one of my minor gripes with stack exchange, you can put up post notices on every post, including questions. The problem is that post notices don't have any variants specific to questions themselves.

Comment: I see. I don't even know what a post notice is, let alone how to post it. Sounds like it would be better to write the text you want. Or if there's a lot of reuse, copy-paste it from an Emacs buffer (file). ;-)

Comment: @Drew Moderators can't edit the text, there are only a few to choose from.

Comment: I don't understand why this function warrants a post notice. On the other hand, I have no idea what it's asking. I would have closed it as unclear.

Comment: Considering how many questions I've closed, I figured I'd be better off posting a comment with suggestions to improve the question, and added a notice so that I do more than just writing a short comment.

Comment: Perhaps moderators can't edit that text, but if that text is not appropriate they (anyone) can write their own text, to say what they think is needed.

Comment: I've just removed the post notice, as the question was edited to flesh it out by OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post) that moderators can leave. It isn't about the shortness of the question, it's about the shortness of answers. It is not specifically shown to the question asker, and the asker is not notified (this is not a comment on the question). It's shown to everyone who *reads* the question. It's reminding potential *answerers* to post answers with explanations and not just one line of code with no context.

Comment: Then I'd say that putting it in a comment for the question is inappropriate. The OP, especially if new, will naturally (a) wonder why it talks about answers and (b) guess that it means to say that the question is too short. And what to do if the question IS too short? In this case there were no answers yet, and the question was very short.

Comment: @Drew This is not a comment on the question. The question asker is not notified. This notice is not about the question.

Comment: Well, it was yesterday. This notice was on the question, not an answer. (But yes, it was applied to the question itself, not in a comment.)

Comment: @Drew Once again, there is nothing in the notice that is addressed to the question asker, and nothing in the content of the notice that is about the question. I don't understand why you find it inappropriate. The message is about answers, addressed to potential answerers.

Comment: The notice says nothing about the question, as you say (and as I said). The notice talks about answers, as you say and as I said. The notice was, in this case, put on the question, not on an answer. That is what I found inappropriate. You don't see it now because it was removed.